# Why does Firebug's HTML panel show characters like ¶ and ·?

Tags: firefox-addon, firebug

[image: Strange characters shown in Firebug's *HTML* panel]

My Firebug's *HTML* panel shows some unwanted characters like ¶ and ·. I can't understand why it shows those characters and it causes trouble while reading the HTML.

Is it some kind of virus or what?

Answer (score 2):

Firebug has an option to toggle the display of non-printable characters within the HTML source called *Show Whitespace* in the [*HTML* panel options](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/HTML_Panel#Options_Menu).

[image: *Show Whitespace* option within *HTML* panel]

This option allows you to see line breaks as ¶, spaces as · and tabs as ‌→ like in word processors.
If you don't want to see the whitespace characters, you need to uncheck that option.